# error in concatinating multiple dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, typeerror, concatenation

hello i am a beginner and stuck in this weird error i am getting

i have 4 dataframes which i want to concatenate

these are 4 DF i have 
`'beds_mntd_bystates', 'beds_mntd_mod', 'beds_mntd_gov', 'beds_mntd_insure'`

```
every dataframe has states in it and count of total no. of hospital 
and total no.of beds there the shape of each DF is also same
            Total_No_of_Hospital    Total_No_of_Beds
States  
Andhra Pradesh   5.0                 345.0
Assam            1.0                 75.0
Bihar            3.0                 50.0
```

```
i made them in a list using
frames_collection=[]
frames_collection.extend(values for values,name in locals().items() if values.startswith('beds_mntd'))
```

the main problem is when i use concat to join all frames
i tried

```
frame_df=pd.concat(frames_collection,axis=1)
```

i am getting a weird error

```
Type Error:cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

i dont know how to deal with this

also  datatype of each of DF is 'object' and columns are 'float' type

Comment: Could you please provide sample input for these dataframes, so others can reproduce your issue?

Comment: I suppose your problem is that you are quoting your DataFrame objects and therefore using them as strings. E.g. use `beds_mntd_bystates` instead of `'beds_mntd_bystates'`. That's what I get from the error message.

Comment: i have added the data now see if something could be done i think that datatype of DF are making some error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure about what you are trying to attempt. Especially without data and expected output.

However, if you just want to concatenate a list of data-frames;

```
df_list = [beds_mntd_bystates, beds_mntd_mod, beds_mntd_gov, beds_mntd_insure]

frame_df = pandas.concat(df_list)
```